# How to access Flask app context from test_client using pytest?

Tags: python, flask, testing, pytest

I feel like I don't fully understand `app_context` and its usage. When I turn my app into a test_client, I can't seem to access the fields that are within the apps context, which means I can't test in my unit tests whether the element was successfully added to the state of the app. How do I access the app context from a `test_client`, as shown below?

Here are minimal sections of the relevant code:

App:

```
def make_service():
    service = Flask("my_service")
    my_content: Dict[str, str] = {}
    with service.app_context():
        service.my_content = my_content
    return service

app = make_service()


@app.route("/test/")
def example_func():
    app.my_content["test"] = "testing entry"
```

Pytest fixture:

```
@pytest.fixture(name="test_app")
def test_client():
    with app.test_client() as testing_client:
        with app.app_context():
            yield testing_client
```

Pytest test function:

```
def test_example_func(test_app):
    response = test_app.get(
        "/test/",
    )
    assert test_app.my_content["test"] == "testing_entry"
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: 'FlaskClient' object has no attribute 'my_content'
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was simpler than expected. I had completely overlooked the fact that `test_client` wraps the `app` and stores it as a variable names `application`.

The solution is to change `test_app.my_content["test"] == "testing_entry"` to `test_app.application.my_content["test"] == "testing_entry"`